# Getting value error when doing scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm new to machine learning and trying to do a hands-on with scikit-learn on a simple classification problem use case i.e. based on name and nationality, the system should suggest whether the Gender should be 1 or 2. The data I have is:

```
<br>
Name    Nationality Gender<br>
John    201           1<br>
Sue     401           2<br>
Smith   401           1<br>
.... Millions of rows (but to start I'm just picking 5000 records)
<br>
```

I'm getting the error 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'John'' while doing 'X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)'
I know it is a very common problem and that algorithms work on numbers and not text. I've tried to go through a number of posts and have found people recommending LabelEncoder or One Hot Encoder, but not able to understand how it will fit here and get simple lines of code that would resolve this. Help appreciated.

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data=pd.read_csv("D:\profile_gender_data.csv")

feature_names = ['FIRST_NAME_EN', 'PRS_NATIONALITY_ID']
X = data[feature_names]
y = data['GENDER_ID']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'John'

Comment: Could you please show us the values of X, you probably have to do X.values

Comment: @MatteoPeluso I don't think that's the problem. The `train_test_split` accepts a `dataframe` as a parameter. The problem is the `FIRST_NAME_EN` is a string. So, if you get X.values, it's still a string. Got it?

Comment: @AndréPacheco Yes, I just wanted to see the values of X :)

Comment: That's fine. I'm saying that based on the chunk of data that was posted.

Answer (score 0):

So, as the code says, you're passing a string instead of a number to the function. When you get `X = data[feature_names]`, the column `'FIRST_NAME_EN'` is a string and it's not allowed to use it as a feature for a model. You need to convert that for a number.

I don't know your problem and it doesn't look to use a name as a feature. But, if want to keep using that, try to convert all names for numbers, for example, John = 0, Sue = 1 and so on. You can use a `dict` or a `list` to achieve that. You also can convert it to `one_hot_encode` in order to get the names as a list of 0-1.

Comment: Instead of a dict, the OP can use `label_encoder`. Will save time.

Comment: @rajatkabra that's true. Good call.

Comment: Please note that I will be having hundreds of thousands of unique values. Will this still be the solution?

Comment: Yes! You need to transform that to numbers. Use the function @rajatkabra suggested and you'll be fine

Comment: @Maarab It depends on the ML model you are using. Some models will work perfectly fine with this but some will go down as they might end up giving more or less importance to feature which is mapped to 1000 compared to the one which is mapped to 0.

Comment: What models then you would suggest for this case as I can already see the accuracy not good since some of the names might appear just a couple of times out of millions?